# JSON parsing invalid response from the server

Tags: android, json

I made a request to the server He should  return JSON
but as a result I get "404" and ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Service</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Service</p>
      <p>Endpoint not found.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

my request Json:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl() {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {



        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = getNewHttpClient();

        String auth = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(
                ("estafeta@62e12548-0a68-4999-960b-a3bb3c44675c:11111")
                        .getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(
                "https://test2.estafeta.org/mobileestafeta/MobileSurveyReportsService.svc/LoadSurveyTasks?startRowVersion=AAAAAAAAAAA=&count=500");

        get.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(get);
        //httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

I need to get the JSON I'm doing wrong? help

Comment: if you get a 404, it means you are not calling the correct address...

Comment: The query I have correctly written?

Comment: i do'nt think your parameters should be written this was. Use UrlEncoder

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to set content type which you want to receive
`get.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: I do not know what to do ... I was given the test task ... the question, what am I doing wrong? - meet "Parameters correctly specified."